# What's the best way to access single gradients in a batch in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm currently analyzing how gradients develop over the course of training of a CNN using Tensorflow 2.x. What I want to do is compare each gradient in a batch to the gradient resulting for the whole batch. At the moment I use this simple code snippet for each training step:

```py
[...]
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
[...]

# One training step
# x_train is a batch of input data, y_train the corresponding labels
def train_step(model, optimizer, x_train, y_train):

    # Process batch
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        batch_predictions = model(x_train, training=True)
        batch_loss = loss_object(y_train, batch_predictions)
    batch_grads = tape.gradient(batch_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    # Do something with gradient of whole batch
    # ...

    # Process each data point in the current batch
    for index in range(len(x_train)):
        with tf.GradientTape() as single_tape:
            single_prediction = model(x_train[index:index+1], training=True)
            single_loss = loss_object(y_train[index:index+1], single_prediction)
        single_grad = single_tape.gradient(single_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        # Do something with gradient of single data input
        # ...

    # Use batch gradient to update network weights
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(batch_grads, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(batch_loss)
    train_accuracy(y_train, batch_predictions)
```

My main problem is that computation time explodes when calculating each of the gradients single-handedly although these calculations should have already been done by Tensorflow when calculating the batch's gradient. The reason is that `GradientTape` as well as `compute_gradients` always return a single gradient no matter whether single or several data points were given. So this computation has to be done for each data point.

I know that I could compute the batch's gradient to update the network by using all the single gradients calculated for each data point but this plays only a minor role in saving computation time.

Is there a more efficient way to compute single gradients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) method of the gradient tape to get the Jacobian matrix, which will give you the gradients for each individual loss value:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Make a random linear problem
tf.random.set_seed(0)
# Random input batch of ten four-vector examples
x = tf.random.uniform((10, 4))
# Random weights
w = tf.random.uniform((4, 2))
# Random batch label
y = tf.random.uniform((10, 2))
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(w)
    # Prediction
    p = x @ w
    # Loss
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, p)
# Compute Jacobian
j = tape.jacobian(loss, w)
# The Jacobian gives you the gradient for each loss value
print(j.shape)
# (10, 4, 2)
# Gradient of the loss wrt the weights for the first example
tf.print(j[0])
# [[0.145728424 0.0756840706]
#  [0.103099883 0.0535449386]
#  [0.267220169 0.138780832]
#  [0.280130595 0.145485848]]
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I could just replace my `tape.gradient(batch_loss, model.trainable_variables)` call with `tape.jacobian(batch_loss, model.trainable_variables)`, right? If I do that, (for a batch size of 250 and 8 layer CNN) I still get a `j` of size 8 (not 250 as I would expect), which means I get the gradients per layer not per input date. You know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @ItsMarvolo Well, it depends on the rest of your code, namely on `loss_object`. What I posted works assuming your `batch_loss` is a 1D tensor with one loss value per example in the batch. But if `loss_object` already aggregates the batch loses in a single value, or outputs something else, then you would need to make other changes...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. I added the current `loss_object` to my question. You're right about the loss being aggregated to a single value. If I add `reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` to the `loss_object` my `optimizer.apply_gradients(..)` call breaks now because of the additional dimension. I will work on that and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: Got it to work! This cuts the computation time by approx. one third, thanks a lot! Did I get it right that calculating the mean (e.g. using `tf.reduce_mean(...)`) of the resulting values for one batch using `tape.jacobian(...)` produce the same result as using `tape.gradient(...)`? After processing the single gradients I use this to update the network afterwards (`optimizer.apply_gradients(...)`) without having to update my old optimizer

Comment: @ItsMarvolo In general, to obtain the "normal" gradients from the Jacobian (what you would get by calling `gradient`, that is) you would sum the values (`gradient` computes the gradients with respect to the sum of `target` values). Computing the mean would be equivalent to the gradient of the average loss (the gradient you would get with `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` reduction).

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify: the tensorflow documentation states that "for almost all cases" the `AUTO` reduction defaults to `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE`. This should be the case in my initial post where no reduction is specified. So the results for `..SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` + `tape.gradient(...)` should equal the new results for `..SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(..NONE)` + `tape.jacobian(...)` + `tf.reduce_mean(..)`. Maybe this helps someone struggling at the same point I am.

Comment: @ItsMarvolo Thanks for the additional info, that sounds right. Forgot to mention, in cases where you need the gradients of the loss wrt the inputs, you can use [`batch_jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian) instead, which will be faster (working under the assumption that each `y[i]` depends only on `x[i]`).  But I don't think it applies in your case.