# Tensorflow calculate hessian of model weights in a batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, vectorization

I am replicating a paper. I have a basic Keras CNN model for MNIST classification. Now for sample `z` in the training, I want to calculate the hessian matrix of the model parameters with respect to the loss of that sample. I want to average out this hessian over the training data (`n` is number of training data).

[image]

My final goal is to calculate this value (the influence score):

[image]

I can calculate the left term and the right term and want to compute the Hessian term. I don't know how to calculate hessian for the model weights for a batch of examples (vectorization). I was able to calculate it only for a sample at a time which is too slow.

```
x=tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train[0:13])
with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
    with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
      y=model(x)
      mce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
      y_expanded=y_train[train_idx]
      loss=mce(y_expanded,y)
    g = t1.gradient(loss, model.weights[4])
h = t2.jacobian(g, model.weights[4])
print(h.shape)
```

For clarification, if a model layer is of dimension `20*30`, I want to feed a batch of `13` samples to it and get a Hessian of dimension `(13,20,30,20,30)`. Now I can only get Hessian of dimension `(20,30,20,30)` which thwarts the vectorization (the code above).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261134/whats-the-best-way-to-access-single-gradients-in-a-batch-in-tensorflow) has the same problem, except that I want the second-order derivative rather than the first-order.

I also tried the below script which returns a `(13,20,30,20,30)` matrix that satisfies the dimension, but when I manually checked the sum of this matrix with the sum of `13` single hessian calculations with a for loop from `0` to `12`, they lead to different numbers so it does not work either since I expected equal values.

```
x=tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train[0:13])
mce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)

with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
    with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
      t1.watch(model.weights[4])
      y_expanded=y_train[0:13]
      y=model(x)
      loss=mce(y_expanded,y)
    j1=t1.jacobian(loss, model.weights[4])
j3 = t2.jacobian(j1, model.weights[4])

print(j3.shape)
```

Comment: Always start with reading the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/hessians and https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#example_hessian

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy That is true and I already checked that, but how could I pass a batch and compute jacobians w.r.t model parameters as a batch?  The question was also formatted to address the guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Let's Suppose you have a model and you wanna train the model weights by taking the Hessian of the training images w.r.t trainable-weights

```
#Import the libraries we need
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.eager import forwardprop
```

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

```
#Define the Adam Optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98,
                                     epsilon=1e-9)
```

```
#Define the loss function
def loss_function(y_true , y_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true , y_pred , from_logits=True)

#Define the Accuracy metric function
def accuracy_function(y_true , y_pred):
    return tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true , y_pred)
```

```
Now, define the variables for storing the mean of the loss and accuracy
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='accuracy')
```

```
#Now compute the Hessian in some different style for better efficiency of the model
vector = [tf.ones_like(v) for v in model.trainable_variables]

def _forward_over_back_hvp(images, labels):
    
    with forwardprop.ForwardAccumulator(model.trainable_variables, vector) as acc:
        with tf.GradientTape() as grad_tape:
            logits = model(images, training=True)
            loss = loss_function(labels ,logits)
        grads = grad_tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    hessian = acc.jvp(grads)
    
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(hessian, model.trainable_variables))
    
    train_loss(loss) #keep adding the loss
    train_accuracy(accuracy_function(labels, logits)) #Keep adding the accuracy
```

```
#Now, here we need to call the function and train it
import time
for epoch in range(20):
    start = time.time()

    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()

    for i,(x , y) in enumerate(dataset):
        _forward_over_back_hvp(x , y)

    if(i%50==0):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} Loss {train_loss.result():.4f} Accuracy {train_accuracy.result():.4f}')

        print(f'Time taken for 1 epoch: {time.time() - start:.2f} secs\n')
```

```
Epoch 1 Loss 2.6396 Accuracy 0.1250
Time is taken for 1 epoch: 0.23 secs
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I tried to reproduce your code for a model and calculate hessian for an arbitrary layer of the model. Could you please extend your approach for h5 models?

Comment: You were asking about the Hessian Matrix, Now you have changed your question... So, kindly elaborate on it first.

Comment: Hi Mohammad. As I mentioned in the question title and body, I am interested in calculating the Hessian loss for a batch of samples with respect to model layers.

Comment: Yeah, Ok but now the bounty period is over now :(

Comment: It is, but if you want, you could edit your previous answer and if it works I can still give the bounty. But please also double check the results with the sequential (non-batched) implementation with a for loop, to check your answer works :)

Comment: what do you mean **Non-Batched**? So, do you need to compute the **Hessian** w.r.t loss as a single batch?

Comment: In last you wanna compute the *Hessian* of a `Sequential` Model using the MNIST dataset, w.r.t the categorical loss?

Comment: Non-batched is computing it using a CPU for a single example. The purpose of a question is to compute Hessian for a batch of `N` examples using GPU, which yields the same result as feeding each example to the CPU one by one. The goal is to vectorize it and increase speed. Yes, the model is `Sequential` and the loss is categorical. The final goal of this is not training using second-order optimization, is just Hessian values are needed to compute explicit influence values. I'll check your implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I got it. SO now the code will change. This code is used to train the model, you are asking for something different! I will update it.

Comment: Yes. Just refer to the understanding black-box predictions via influence functions paper and you see why Hessian is required.

Answer (score 1):

That's how hessians are defined, you can only calculate a hessian of a scalar function.

But nothing new here, the same happens with gradients, and what is done to handle batches is to accumulate the gradients, something similar can be done with the hessian.

If you know how to compute the hessian of the `loss`, it means you could define batch `cost` and still be able to compute the hessian with the same method. e.g. you could define your `cost` as the `sum(losses)` where `losses` is the vector of losses for all examples in the batch.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for your response. I had tried this initially, but when I compare this approach with the approach of calculating the Hessian one by one and accumulating them (as the ground truth), the results are notably different when I do np.sum over them. I expect to get the same result, and the sum values are unrelated (i.e, one is not average per number of elements)